# How to group by a column and give duplicate values as 1 and original values as 0

Tags: python, dataframe, date, group-by, rank

I have a data frame :-

```
         Date bikes
0   28/12/2021  zw12
1   28/12/2021  zw11
2   28/12/2021  zw13
3   28/12/2021  zw14
4   26/12/2021  zw11
5   25/12/2021  zw11
6   23/12/2021  zw12
7   20/12/2021  zw12
8   19/12/2021  zw11
9   22/05/2020  zw11
10  24/05/2020  zw12
```

Now I want to group by column 'bikes' with respective to the latest date from column 'Date'. So, for that I have used created a column 'Rank' which assigns the latest records as 1 and the old/duplicates records to be 2. I tried to do this as below:-

```
df_rank=df.assign(rank=df.groupby('bikes')['Date'].transform(lambda x: x.rank())) \
  .sort_values('Date',ascending = False)
print(df_rank)
          Date bikes  rank
0   28/12/2021  zw12   4.0
1   28/12/2021  zw11   5.0
2   28/12/2021  zw13   1.0
3   28/12/2021  zw14   1.0
4   26/12/2021  zw11   4.0
5   25/12/2021  zw11   3.0
10  24/05/2020  zw12   3.0
6   23/12/2021  zw12   2.0
9   22/05/2020  zw11   2.0
7   20/12/2021  zw12   1.0
8   19/12/2021  zw11   1.0
```

As you can see that rank function is not assigning as I wanted. Am I using it in a wrong way?
I want the latest/original  record with 0 and the duplicate/old records with 1 in the column 'Rank'.

Desired output:-

```
            Date bikes  rank
    0   28/12/2021  zw12   1.0   
    1   28/12/2021  zw11   1.0
    2   28/12/2021  zw13   1.0
    3   28/12/2021  zw14   1.0
    4   26/12/2021  zw11   2.0
    5   25/12/2021  zw11   2.0
    10  24/05/2020  zw12   2.0
    6   23/12/2021  zw12   2.0
    9   22/05/2020  zw11   2.0
    7   20/12/2021  zw12   2.0
    8   19/12/2021  zw11   2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `Date` column is of type datetime, then:

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(count)

df = df.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=False)
df["rank"] = (
    df.groupby("Date", sort=False)["bikes"]
    .transform(lambda x: [next(d[v]) for v in x])
    .gt(0)
    .astype(int)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Date bikes  rank
6  2021-12-28  zw12     0
7  2021-12-28  zw11     0
8  2021-12-28  zw13     0
9  2021-12-28  zw14     0
10 2021-12-26  zw11     1
0  2021-12-25  zw11     1
1  2021-12-23  zw12     1
2  2021-12-20  zw12     1
3  2021-12-19  zw11     1
5  2020-05-24  zw12     1
4  2020-05-22  zw11     1
```

Comment: @Pysdm `.gt` is "greater". Similar to `>` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html#pandas.DataFrame.gt